# Display ANSI colours in a Slack Snippet

Tags: logging, slack, hubot, ansi-colors

I am using Slack and Hubot to run a few commands on our servers, the stdout and stderr of these commands is uploaded to a channel as a snippet.

Some of these commands return colour outputs and are displayed in the snippet as ANSI colour codes (example: [32mHello World![0m).

Is there a way to display these colours in a Slack Snippet?

Comment: Hey @Shipra did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: Not yet. I don't think Slack supports it as of yet. :(

Answer (score 0):

```js
def enviarNotificacionSlack(mensaje, estado) {
    // Convert ANSI color codes to Slack message formatting
    def formattedMensaje = mensaje.replaceAll('\u001B\\[39m', '*')
                                   .replaceAll('\u001B\\[90m', '`')
                                   .replaceAll('\u001B\\[32m', '*')
                                   .replaceAll('\u001B\\[31m', '`')

    // Construct the Slack message payload
    def slackMessage = [
        channel: '#channel',
        attachments: [
            [
                fallback: mensaje,
                color: estado == 'success' ? 'good' : 'danger',
                text: formattedMensaje
            ]
        ]
    ]

    // Send the Slack notification
    slackSend(slackMessage)
}
```